# Does WebDAV support file PUT resume? Or upload in multiple chunks?

Tags: webdav

I need to upload a file using WebDAV and my issue is that the server limits upload to max 100MB. Is there a way to upload it in chunks (so multiple requests to bypass this 100MB limitation)? The server does allow you to have larger files there so I'm ok if I'm able to get it there. The limitation is only on the upload part.

Answer (score 5):

WebDAV `PUT` is the same as HTTP `PUT`. `PUT`, as specified, does not support resumable uploads. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.B.p.7.

Either the server needs to be fixed to allow larger `PUT` operations, or you'll have to check whether it supports a custom protocol for resumable uploads.