# Upload large files to WebDAV with resume support

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, webdav, resume-upload

I want to upload large files to ownCloud with WebDAV API.

I use this code to do this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://user:password@owncloud.local/remote.php/webdav/test.mp4";
$localfile = "test.mp4";
$fp = fopen ($localfile, "r");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
$http_result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch ,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
print $http_code;
print "<br /><br />$http_result";
if ($error) {
   print "<br /><br />$error";
}
?>
```

But when connection lost, this script cannot resume uploading file.

Is it possible to resume file upload with WebDAV?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My below old answer is how to use CURL API for resuming transfer.

But truth is that WebDAV does not seem to support resumable uploads:
[Does WebDAV support file PUT resume? Or upload in multiple chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28411893/850848)

---

Use the [`CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE` option](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE.html).

Either set it to a position to start the resume from. Or use the `-1` to make the curl automatically resume at the end of the partially uploaded file.

Note that this affects the remote side only. You also need to seek the local file read pointer to the same position (using the [`fseek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)). So, if you want to resume at the end of the partially uploaded file, you need to query its size first, to know where to seek the local file read pointer to.
For that see [Remote file size without downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602612/850848).