# Resumable upload with CURL in owncloud

Tags: php, curl, owncloud

I am uploading my files to owncloud using curl request. If connection interrupts how can resume the upload? because i have to upload large files. Below is my code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/' . basename($filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

    $fh_res = fopen($file_path_str, 'r');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE); // --data-binary
    $curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
```

How to continue the upload if the connection interrupts?

Comment: HTTP has no (standard) way to resume uploads.

Comment: How this can be used  " CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM "

Comment: @DanielStenberg  how " CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM " can be used to resume upload in my script?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you make your server end accept that way of doing it. As I said, it's not a HTTP standard thing.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Do you know the best method i can upload my files to owncloud using php? I found only this curl method.

Comment: Anybody can answer this?

Comment: See [Upload large files to WebDAV with resume support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32952124/850848) - If you have a specific problem with implementing the steps there, show us what did you try and how it fails.

Comment: Hi martin i am able to upload to ownlcoud my question is how to resume the upload if in case the connnection is lost?   i found this   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM_LARGE, resume_position);   But how can i find the    resume_position ?

Comment: That's covered at the end of my answer to the linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload large files to WebDAV with resume support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952124/upload-large-files-to-webdav-with-resume-support)